# Improving performance for huge table. Partition? Dropping an id and keeping a unique constraint instead? mysql

Tags: mysql, performance, amazon-rds

At my company we have a table that has gotten too large. It has only 4 fields and the indices are shared below. Note that our data is separated by region so we have the same schema in 2 separate databases(one for NA and one for EU). The data below is for EU, but NA generally has 10x as much data as EU.

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | bigint(20) unsigned | NO | PRI | NULL | auto_increment |
| other_table_id | int(11) | NO | MUL | NULL |  |
| time_index | int(11) | NO |  | NULL |  |
| value | decimal(18,6) | YES |  | NULL |  |

| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| my_table | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | id | A | 833155696 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| my_table | 0 | index_other_table_and_time_index | 1 | other_table_id | A | 29755560 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |
| my_table | 0 | index_other_table_and_time_index | 2 | time_index | A | 833155696 | NULL | NULL |  | BTREE |  |  |

Note that other_table_id is an id for another table but it isn't enforced at the db level. (Enforced at rails application level). Also note that the non primary index has a unique constraint on it.

We only really have 2 queries on this table. Our insert is a batch insert of the following form:

```
INSERT INTO my_table (value, time_index, other_table_id) 
VALUES (1,2,3),(4,5,6)...<5000-10000 tuples later>... (7,8,9) 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
my_table.value=VALUES(value), 
my_table.time_index=VALUES(time_index), 
my_table.other_table_id=VALUES(other_table_id);
```

Our query is the following:

```
select other_table_id, time_index, value from my_table where
(other_table_id in (<3000 values>) and time_index between 5800 and 6050 )
or (other_table_id in (<300 values>) and time_index between 800 and 830)
order by other_table_id, time_index;
```

This table has grown since 2006. We see query and insert times > 60 seconds frequently. (Can see it in mysql slow query logs). We are using the largest instance AWS offers in RDS and we've tuned the IO / memory.

Therefore I'm trying to think of other ways to improve the performance.

I was wondering if I would get a significant benefit from removing the id field? In that case, it would be one less value needed during insert. I also thought about partitioning based on the time index since most queries use a time index that is recent. However I have read that partitioning takes the db offline and I would be scared to partition a db this big. It's unclear how long the db would be off.

Would removing the id field give me any major benefits? Would partitioning give me major benefits? If so is there a way to do partition without downtime? Note I have to drop the id field before partitioning because mysql requires all index keys to be in the partition. I was thinking of partitioning on time_index.

What other options might there be? We don't have read replicas so one other option is to move read queries to a read replica. However it's unclear to me if that would get significant wins since our issue is more table size and not load. Note that EU has ~833M rows while NA has ~3.9B rows.

Edit: For clarification value is a scientific measurement. I'm not sure the business will allow me to edit it. Also I added explain query on the read query below:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | my_table | range | index_other_table_and_time_index | index_other_table_and_time_index | 8 | NULL | 3432 | Using index condition |

Also adding an explain query on the union suggestion:

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | PRIMARY | my_table | range | index_other_table_and_time_index | index_other_table_and_time_index | 8 | NULL | 3118 | Using index condition |
| 2 | UNION | my_table | range | index_other_table_and_time_index | index_other_table_and_time_index | 8 | NULL | 314 | Using index condition |
| NULL | UNION RESULT | <union1,2> | ALL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | Using temporary; Using filesort |

As requested explain statement as json:

```
{
    "query_block": {
        "select_id": 1,
        "ordering_operation": {
            "using_filesort": false,
            "table": {
                "table_name": "my_table",
                "access_type": "range",
                "possible_keys": [
                    "index_other_table_and_time_index"
                ],
                "key": "index_other_table_and_time_index",
                "used_key_parts": [
                    "other_table_id",
                    "time_index"
                ],
                "key_length": "8",
                "rows": 3432,
                "filtered": 100,
                "index_condition": "(((`mydb`.`my_table`.`other_table_id` in (...list of values)) and (`mydb`.`my_table`.`time_index` between 5800 and 6050)) or ((`mydb`.`my_table`.`other_table_id` in (...list of values...)) and (`mydb`.`my_table`.`time_index` between 800 and 830)))"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you have `UNIQUE(other_table_id, time_index)`.  Yes, it makes sense to jettison the auto_increment and promote that to `PRIMARY`

What is the semantics of `value`?  If it is money, then do you really need to hold a trillion dollars/euros, to 6 decimal places?

If `value` is 'scientific', how many 'significant digits' do you need to keep?  `FLOAT` (4 bytes) will give you about 7, with a wide 'range'.  That is much smaller than your 9-byte `DECIMAL`.

The phrasing of the IODKU seems 'incorrect'.  If it decides to "update" (as opposed to "insert"), then there is no need for this pair:

```
my_table.time_index=VALUES(time_index), 
my_table.other_table_id=VALUES(other_table_id);
```

Your query would run a lot faster this way:

```
    (   SELECT  other_table_id, time_index, value
             from  my_table
            WHERE  other_table_id in (<3000 values>)
              and  time_index between 5800 AND 6050 
    )
    UNION  
    (   SELECT  other_table_id, time_index, value
             from  my_table
            WHERE  other_table_id in (<300 values>)
              and  time_index between 800 AND 830 
    )
    order by  other_table_id, time_index;
```

because it could use the index twice instead of doing a full table scan (nearly a billion rows).  It would also be faster because of the change in PK.

(I think Partitioning would not help.)

Comment: Value is not a monetary value. It's a scientific measurement. I don't think the business will allow that to change. Regarding the insert, that is a good catch. Also regarding the read query that is another good catch. I'll try these out and see if it makes a change. Also, for the updating primary key, is it as simple as `ALTER TABLE my_table DROP COLUMN id, ADD PRIMARY KEY (other_table_id, time_index);`? Just wondering if I need to then remove the unique constraint after adding the primary key. Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: I  ran an explain on the read query with and without doing a union. I don't think there will be any benefit. Please take a look and let me know if you agree. I edited the question to add the explain query

Comment: @TerenceChow - I am surprised that the `OR` generated a single line of `EXPLAIN`.  If allowed, please provide the exact queries and `EXPLAIN FORMAT=JSON SELECT ...`  (You can leave out most of the '3000 values'.)  Meanwhile, I added to my answer, re `value`.

Comment: Added the explain in json format.

Comment: It should not hurt to add `INDEX(time_index)`; it may help.